# How to use regex to match numbers in a specified string

Tags: java, regex, burp

For string:
  `Tm_leo_5776045435d31dc2fcb78afd31c2cdb0=1530134325;
   User=687685&CouponCode=329472&whoami=109777`

I want to extract `whoami` field from the above texts but I only want the number digits part. Right now I am using `<?(whoami=)\d{6,8}` but this will extract the string `whoami=109777` and I want to get rid of the string `whoami=`.

Comment: You want [`(?<=whoami=)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/CzfRNp/1).

Comment: What is the regex library/programming language?

Comment: It is java. It is for a burp suite extension.

Comment: So, my approach should work then.

Answer (score 4):

You may use a regex with a **positive lookbehind**:

```
(?<=whoami=)[0-9]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CzfRNp/2). Or, you may require `&` or `?` to appear right before `whoami` and use

```
(?<=[&?]whoami=)[0-9]+
    ^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CzfRNp/3).

The `(?<=[&?]whoami=)`, a positive lookbehind, checks if there is `whoami=` substring with `&` or `?` in front immediately to the left of the current location, and `[0-9]+` matches and consumes one or more digits and returns just this text.

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap the matched digits in a group and read that grouping from the match result.

`<?whoami=(\d{6,8})`

You'll want group 1 from the resulting match.

Group 0 will be the entire match, group 1 will be the matched number.

Comment: Why group `whoami=` when you can use a lookbehind?

Comment: @pkpkpk good point...I was updating my answer with the same as you were typing.

Comment: It is not working for me. I tried on http://www.regexe.com and it is still matching the entire `whoami=109777` field..